# Get request not working for "&" while sending data over url though Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, html-encode

i have few data in Android Spinner. While select item though spinner i want to check them if they are available in DB with a Get request. i can check almost every item in my Spinner item except those who have "&" within them.
Example : **i can check** "A" or "A and B" or "A-B" 
But **i can't check** "A & B" type strings. 
Here is my code.

```
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner)sender;
        var routetext = spinner.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position).ToString();
        var mainroutetext = Android.Text.TextUtils.HtmlEncode(routetext);




        try
        {

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var uri = new Uri(string.Format("http://www.codexen.net/api/Android/getrouteid?name=" + spinner.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position).ToString()));
            HttpResponseMessage response; ;
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            response = await client.GetAsync(uri);

            if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Accepted)
            {
                var errorMessage1 = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.Replace("\\", "").Trim(new char[1] { '"' });


                Toast.MakeText(this, errorMessage1, ToastLength.Long).Show();


            }
            else
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Failed", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }
```

Comment: You should urlEncode the string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `&` character in a query string is used as a separator between parameters. That's why when you issue a GET petition with a parameter value or name containing `&`, it fails. To avoid this, you need to [URL Encode](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP) your strings.

Use this method to urlencode your string before sending it in your request.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/zttxte6w(v=vs.110).aspx

```
var uri = new Uri(string.Format("http://www.codexen.net/api/Android/getrouteid?name={0}",HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode(spinner.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position))));
```

Also, notice that we use string. Format because of the "string pool" problem. You use placeholders like `{0} {1}` and so on in your string, and then append the variables that you'll like to be printed as parameters.

**Edit C#6.**

Starting with C# v.6 you can use the more convenient string interpolation syntax instead:

```
var uri = new Uri($"http://www.codexen.net/api/Android/getrouteid?name={HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode(spinner.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position))}");
```

Note the `$` before the quotes in your string, enabling interpolation with `{}`.

Comment: Thanks :) sir. Allthough my conversion was not working then :(